# Does anybody know of a CSS analysis tool?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a tool that can analyze a large site and look for orphaned css.

I work on this project that has gone through a couple of UI updates.  Scrapping the whole thing and redoing it all would take forever.  What I would like is a tool that reads a css file and then lets you browse the site, keeping track of what definitions were used and how often.

Then I can go through the css file and find code that I did use and determine if it is indeed deprecated and can be deleted.

Thoughts?

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Rodrigo, what is your job title?

Comment: http://www.testmycss.com performs static analysis on your css

Answer (score 9):

Firefox has a great extension called [Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) for flagging up classes/ids that are not used on the current page.

There's also [TopStyle](http://www.topstyle4.com/), which promises to help you do the following (I've not used it, and can't vouch for it though):

- Preview CSS while you write it.
- Easily create pleasant color schemes for your site.
- Style Checker validates your CSS syntax against multiple browsers.
- Use Site Reports to see at-a-glance where CSS styles are used in your site.
- Style Upgrade quickly replaces all outdated HTML code with equivalent CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8 has this feature called Developer Tools which can help you with that. You can read about it from the [IEBlog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/03/07/improved-productivity-through-internet-explorer-8-developer-tools.aspx). If you don't have IE8 you can download the [toolbar from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest CSSEdit. Been using it for years. Has an inbuilt validator and an x-ray inspector.